# On latex beamer the miniframes circles get cut on the bottom section by the frame title

Tags: beamer, mini-frames

Basically this happens.

[image: Basically this happens]

This is my document config

```
\documentclass[compress]{beamer}
\usetheme{Warsaw}
\useoutertheme{infolines}
\useoutertheme[subsection=false]{miniframes}
```

Ive tried searching the reason but cant find anything.
Using other theme, like Madrid, solves de issue but I would like to use Warsaw if possible.

Comment: Welcome to TSE. A question should be written in such a way that it can be understood even by someone who did not read the title.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the following lines after `\useoutertheme[subsection=false]{miniframes}`:

```
\usepackage{xpatch}
\makeatletter
\xpatchcmd\beamer@@tmpl@headline{%
  \vskip2pt\insertnavigation{\paperwidth}\vskip2pt%
}{%
  \vskip2pt\insertnavigation{\paperwidth}\vskip5pt% modify 5pt to change the distance
}{}{}
\makeatother
```

This patches code defined in `texmf-dist/tex/latex/beamer/beamerouterthememiniframes.sty`.

[image]

```
\documentclass[compress]{beamer}
\usetheme{Warsaw}
\useoutertheme{infolines}
\useoutertheme[subsection=false]{miniframes}
\usepackage{xpatch}
\makeatletter
\xpatchcmd\beamer@@tmpl@headline{%
  \vskip2pt\insertnavigation{\paperwidth}\vskip2pt%
}{%
  \vskip2pt\insertnavigation{\paperwidth}\vskip5pt% modify 5pt to change the distance
}{}{}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\section{A}
\begin{frame}{a}
\end{frame}
\begin{frame}{b}
\end{frame}
\section{B}
\begin{frame}{a}
\end{frame}
\begin{frame}{b}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```